# LinkedList implementation, where's the wrong in deleteLast() method

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I implemented LikedList in Java, everything working fine except deleteLast() method. I am relatively new, so failed debugging the issue despite being so trivial a problem

This is my implementation code in Java
Where did I make the mistake?

```
package linkedlist;

public class LinkedList {
    private static Node first;
    private static Node last;

    private static class Node {
        private int value;
        private Node next;


        public Node(int val, Node nxt) {
            this.value = val;
            this.next = nxt;
        }

        public Node(int val) {
            this.value = val;
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            addFirst(7);
            addFirst(6);
            addFirst(5);
            addFirst(4);
            addFirst(3);
            addFirst(2);
            addFirst(1);
            System.out.println("-----First And Last Node-----");
            System.out.println(first.value);
            System.out.println(last.value);
            deleteFirst();
            System.out.println("----After Deleting 1st Node------");
            System.out.println(first.value);
            System.out.println(last.value);
            deleteLast();
            System.out.println("-----After Deleting Last Node-----");
            System.out.println(first.value);
            System.out.println(last.value);
            deleteLast();
            System.out.println("-----After Deleting Last Node-----");
            System.out.println(first.value);
            System.out.println(last.value);
        }

        public static void addFirst(int val) {
            if (first == null) {
                first = last = new Node(val, null);
            } else {
                first = new Node(val, first);
            }
        }
        public static void addLast(int val) {
            if (first == null) {
                first = last = new Node(val, null);
            } else {
                last.next = new Node(val, null);
                last = last.next;
            }
        }

        public static void deleteFirst() {
            Node temp = first.next;
            first.next = null;
            first = temp;
            temp.next = null;
        }

        public static void deleteLast() {
            Node current = first;
            Node newLast = first;
            while (current != null) {
                if(current == last) break;
                newLast = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
            newLast.next = null;
            last = newLast;

        }

        public static int indexOf(int val) {
            Node current = first;
            int index = 0;
            while (current.value != val) {
                current = current.next;
                index++;
            }
            return index;
        }
    }
}
```

---

The way the code is, whenever I run it the 1st and last node becomes of the same value, like for the above example code, after deleteLast() method 1st and last both nodes become 2 or having the value 2, which essentially means they are the same exact nodes

Output

```
-----First And Last Node-----
1
7
----After Deleting 1st Node------
2
7
-----After Deleting Last Node-----
2
2
-----After Deleting Last Node-----
2
2
```

Comment: How did you try to debug the issue?
 Put some breakpoints in places while stepping through the code and have a look at the values that are in the variables and what the code is actually doing.

Comment: Problem is in `deleteFirst` - so even though the output shows `2 7` which seems correct, in fact the `2` element has a `next` of null so your list is corrupt.  Subsequent operations would yield unexpected results.  In `deleteFirst` the last line is suspect `temp.next = null;` when `temp` is already set to the next node (2).  Better diagnostics would include "walking" the list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `deleteFirst`: it always truncates the list to be at most one node.

The final statement `temp.next = null` should be removed, as it is identical to doing `first.next = null`. This is the correction:

```
    public static void deleteFirst() {
        Node temp = first.next;
        first.next = null;
        first = temp;
    }
```

But there should be no need to set the `next` member to `null` of the node that is being removed. It could just be:

```
    public static void deleteFirst() {
        first = first.next;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure if you've kept track of `last` properly, your logic in `deleteLast()` is unnecessarily complicated. You could easily just loop until `curr.next.next` is null then set `curr.next` to null and set `last` to `curr`.

Something like this:

```
public static void deleteLast() {
    node curr = first;
    while (curr.next.next != null) {
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    curr.next = null;
    last = curr;
}
```

Since you haven't shared exactly what the error is, there could be other reasons why your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

@trincot has the correct answer - in my testing it seemed helpful to add a "walk the list" to uncover issues which you had.  So here's that method:

```
public static void walkList() {
    Node n = first;
    System.out.print("Walk: ");
    while (n != null) {
        System.out.print(n.value+" ");
        n = n.next;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Adding a call to `walkList` after each operation yields a "before fix" and "after fix":

### Before Fix

```
-----First And Last Node-----
1
7
Walk: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
----After Deleting 1st Node------
2
7
Walk: 2 
-----After Deleting Last Node-----
2
2
Walk: 2 
-----After Deleting Last Node-----
2
2
Walk: 2
```

### After Fix

```
-----First And Last Node-----
1
7
Walk: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
----After Deleting 1st Node------
2
7
Walk: 2 3 4 5 6 7 
-----After Deleting Last Node-----
2
6
Walk: 2 3 4 5 6 
-----After Deleting Last Node-----
2
5
Walk: 2 3 4 5
```